# Hibernate Mysql CommunicationsException MESSAGE: Communications link failure Last packet sent to the server was 47 ms ago

Tags: hibernate, mysql-error-1064

I am facing following error.

Actually i am setting current date in one of my database table through my web app.Next i would like to enter other date's into to my table for that  i tried to change the system date  and  then when wheh i switch my web app unable to do databse related operation. i am facing the following error .

I am using netbeans  6.8, Mysqlconnector 5.1.7,Hibernate3

I need solution for this.

when i change the system time i get the following error  in my web application

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:811)
        at org.bluewhale.dao.HibernateDao.checkLogin(HibernateDao.java:340)
        at org.apache.jsp.LoginProcess_jsp._jspService(LoginProcess_jsp.java:63)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed due to underlying exception/error:
```

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException
MESSAGE: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 47 ms ago.

STACKTRACE:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 47 ms ago.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3009)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2895)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3438)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1951)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2101)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2554)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1761)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1912)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
        at org.bluewhale.dao.HibernateDao.getClients(HibernateDao.java:105)
        at org.apache.jsp.SalesGrid_jsp._jspService(SalesGrid_jsp.java:74)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:113)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:160)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:188)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2452)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2906)
        ... 42 more


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **


        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1115)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4111)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4077)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:505)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:423)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1547)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:673)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
        ... 31 more
username11
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:811)
        at org.bluewhale.dao.HibernateDao.checkLogin(HibernateDao.java:340)
        at org.apache.jsp.LoginProcess_jsp._jspService(LoginProcess_jsp.java:63)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed due to underlying exception/error:


** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException
MESSAGE: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 47 ms ago.

STACKTRACE:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 47 ms ago.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3009)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2895)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3438)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1951)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2101)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2554)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1761)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1912)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
        at org.bluewhale.dao.HibernateDao.getClients(HibernateDao.java:105)
        at org.apache.jsp.SalesGrid_jsp._jspService(SalesGrid_jsp.java:74)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:113)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:160)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:188)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2452)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2906)
        ... 42 more
```

** END NESTED EXCEPTION **

```
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1115)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4111)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4077)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1547)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:673)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
    ... 31 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the attributes, testOnBorrow, testOnReturn, testOnIdle and other attributes in the connection pool which you might have thought to be completely useless. They are given there for a reason. Read the documentation carefully for the connection pool. I bet you didn't. If you are not using a connection pool, you should.